# Chocolatey installation in docker started to fail, restart due to .NET framework is suddenly needed

Tags: windows, docker, chocolatey

Chocolatey installation started to fail last week. Dockerfile starts with

```
FROM python:3.8.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell","-Command"]
RUN "Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12'; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
```

and log says:

```
Forcing web requests to allow TLS v1.2 (Required for requests to Chocolatey.org)
Getting latest version of the Chocolatey package for download.
Not using proxy.
Getting Chocolatey from https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/2.0.0.
Downloading https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/2.0.0 to C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip
Not using proxy.
Extracting C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocoInstall
Installing Chocolatey on the local machine
The registry key for .Net 4.8 was not found or this is forced

Downloading 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2d6bb6b2-226a-4baa-bdec-798822606ff1/8494001c276a4b96804cde7829c04d7f/ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe' to 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe' - the installer is 100+ MBs, so this could take a while on a slow connection.

Installing 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe' - this may take awhile with no output.

.NET Framework 4.8 was installed, but a reboot is required. 

Please reboot the system and try to install/upgrade Chocolatey again.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement for .NET Framework 4.8 is something which has been talked about for a while, and something which is mentioned in both the release notes, and the upgrade guide.

https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/release-notes#may-31-2023

> Upgrade to target version 4.8 of the .NET Framework - see [#2738](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/2738).

https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/guides/upgrading-to-chocolatey-v2-v6#net-framework-4.8-required

> We recommend you install .NET Framework 4.8 and reboot, before installing or upgrading to Chocolatey CLI v2.0.0. If you are installing Chocolatey in a Docker container, please use an image that already has .NET 4.8 installed or use the [official Chocolatey CLI Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/chocolatey/choco).

You can see the base image that is used for the official Chocolatey Docker Image here:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/develop/docker/Dockerfile.windows#L1

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2016
```

Answer (score 12):

Specifying older chocolatey version in Dockerfile seems to help workaround the issue

```
ENV chocolateyVersion=1.4.0
```

as of previous week this is the version which was downloaded as latest.

Answer (score 1):

For those running into this same issue when installing choco via PowerShell on a machine that cannot be upgraded to .NET 4.8 yet, add this to your PowerShell script to install the prior version of choco and avoid the new .NET 4.8 requirement:

```
$env:chocolateyVersion = '1.4.0'
```

Then also make sure you do **not** have this line later in your script, or else it will upgrade to choco 2.0 and install .NET 4.8

```
choco upgrade chocolatey -y -r
```

Comment: Thank you! Running into an issue with automated deployments on headless machines, and this solved it for us.